# ubuntu 12.10 ntfs Error splicing file: Value too large for defined data type

Tags: ntfs

When files are copied from Windows 7/8 NTFS partition, it throws the following error on some files.

"Error splicing file: Value too large for defined data type"

These files are not random. The copy operation consistently fails on certain files. Some of these files are jpg images with reasonable sizes. Obviously there are no errors when copied to USB drive through Windows 8. Searching by error description shows that mount options can be modified to prevent such errors. But this is not a CIFS share. It is the partition on the same hard drive where Ubuntu is installed.

The files are not corrupted as they can be opened with image viewer.

Any help would be appreciated. I dual boot Windows 8 Pro with Ubuntu 12.10. I am trying to backup windows files using Ubuntu.

Comment: I also have this problem. I have Lubuntu 13.10 with VirtualBox with Windows 8 from another PC (copied by Redo Backup). Windows very slowly and I load from Live Lubuntu 13.10 (in VirtualBox) and trying to copy files to iPod Classic (Ext4).

Comment: Same problem here with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and an NTFS-formatted USB stick. In my case, the NTFS file system had _compression_ enabled, and that was the cause of the problem. Uncompressed (on Windows), then it worked!